# How to create a directory during a module install?

Tags: 7, files

I need to create a directory in `public://` when the module is installed via [`file_prepare_directory()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_prepare_directory/7). I used this code in function `mymodule_install()`:

```
$mydir = 'public://mydir';  
file_prepare_directory($mydir, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);`
```

Upon uninstalling, clear the cache, and installing the module it does not create **mydir**.

Comment: Possible solution from a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117941/file-prepare-directory-does-not-seem-to-be-creating-a-directory/33185696#33185696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the directory where you are creating `directory` is writable?

`file_prepare_directory` checks that the directory exists and is writable.
You can try [drupal_mkdir](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/drupal_mkdir/7) statement to create directory in `hook_install`